# Chrome mis-reading max-height and max-width

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I am really confused...

The alert in the following code doesn't show the right values for max-height and max-width in Chrome. I consistently get values 10% larger than the real ones! In Chrome the alert is: "height: 500, max height x width: 1100 x 2200, padding: 20". In any other browser the values are correct and it was fine in jsfiddle too (run in Chrome).

Am I missing something obvious?

Splitting the compound parseInt/.css("..") gave the same results, ie 1100px 1100

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#mainContent { 
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    max-width: 2000px;
    padding-left: 20px;
} 
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = parseInt($("#mainContent").height());
    var maxHeight = parseInt($("#mainContent").css("max-height"), 10);
    var mainContentWidthPadding = parseInt($("#mainContent").css("padding-left"), 10);
    var maxWidth = parseInt($("#mainContent").css("max-width"), 10);
    alert("height: " + height + ", max height x width: " + maxHeight + " x " + maxWidth + ", padding: " + mainContentWidthPadding);
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="mainContent"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#mainContent {
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    max-width: 2000px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

The border-box value (as opposed to the content-box default) makes the final rendered box the declared width, and any border and padding cut inside the box.

Comment: No difference I'm afraid. It's really bizarre!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!! *Somehow*, the zoom was set to, guess, 110% - and only on that tab! I have no idea how, didn't look there, never use it. ((blush))